Escape Time of Simple Random Walks Between $[a,b]$
For a simple random walk $X_{n}$ starting somewhere between the interval $\left[a,b\right]$, with $a$ and $b$ being integers, and
$$
\tau = \inf\left\{t : X_{n} = a\ \mbox{or}\ b\right\},
$$
my goal is to find $E_{x}\left[\tau\right]$.
I can rewrite $E_{x}\left[\tau\right]$as :
$$
\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[T\right] = 1 + \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}_{x + 1}\left[T\right] + \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}_{x - 1}\left[T\right]
$$
But I'm unable to solve this iterative equation.

Use $\displaystyle\sum_{x = 0}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}_{x} z^{x}$ as a $\displaystyle Generating\ Function$.

I was able to understand Wolf's approach using optimal sampling theorem, could you elaborate a little Felix?

Another (a fairly classical) way is to note that
$$
Y_{n}=X_n^2-n
$$
is a martingale with respect to the natural filtration $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(X_0,\dots,X_n)$:
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y_{n+1}-Y_n\mid \mathcal{F}_n)=\frac12\left((X_n+1)^2-(n+1)\right)
+\frac12\left((X_n-1)^2-(n+1)\right)-(X_n^2-n)=0.
$$
Let $X_0=x$. By the optional stopping theorem,
$$
\mathbb{E} Y_{\tau}=Y_0=x^2.
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\mathbb{E} Y_{\tau}=\mathbb{E} \left[X_{\tau}^2-\tau\right]
=a^2\mathbb{P}(X_\tau=a)+b^2\mathbb{P}(X_\tau=b)-\mathbb{E} \tau
$$
and since by the well-known formula
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_\tau=b)=\frac{x-a}{b-a},\quad \mathbb{P}(X_\tau=a)=\frac{b-x}{b-a},
$$
we have $\mathbb{E}\tau=(b-x)(x-a)$.

Let $u(x):=\Bbb E_x[T]$ and $v(x):=u(x)-u(x-1)$. Because $u$ satisfies a second-order difference equation, $v$ satisfies the simpler first-order recursion
$$
v(x+1)-v(x) = -2,\qquad x=a+1,a+2,\cdots,b.
$$
Solve this recursively to get
$$
v(x) =C-2(x-a+1),\qquad x=a+1,a+2,\cdots,b,
$$
where $C:=v(a+1)$ is to be determined. Sum $v$ to get $u$:
$$
u(x) =\sum_{k=a+1}^x v(k)
$$
This uses the obvious boundary condition $u(a) =0$. Use the other boundary condition $u(b)=0$ to determine $C$.

For any $x\in [a,b]\cap \mathbb Z$, let $e_x=\mathbb E_x[\tau]$. We can rewrite your recurrence relation as
$$
(e_{x+1}-e_x)-(e_x-e_{x-1})=-2\qquad (a+1\le x\le b-1)\tag1
$$
Now, define the sequence $(d_x)_{x=a}^{b-1}$ by $d_x=e_{x+1}-e_x$. Applying $(1)$, we get
$$
d_{x+1}-d_x=-2\qquad (a\le x\le b-2)\tag2
$$
$(2)$ then implies that $d_x$ is a linearly growing function of $x$ with slope $-2$, that is,
$$
d_x=d_a-2(x-a)\quad (a\le x\le b-1)\tag3
$$
We can recover $e_x$ from $d_x$:
$$
\begin{align}
e_x
&=e_a+(e_{a+1}-e_a)+(e_{a+2}-e_{a+1})+\dots+(e_x-e_{x-1})
\\
&=0+d_a+d_{a+1}+\dots+d_{x-1}
\\
&=d_a+(d_a-2)+(d_a-4)+\dots+(d_a-2(x-1-a))
\\
&= d_a\cdot (x-a)-\sum_{i=0}^{x-1-a}2i
\\
e_x&=d_a\cdot (x-a)-(x-a)(x-a-1)\tag4
\end{align}
$$
We will be done once we determine the missing parameter $d_a$. We finish up by applying $(4)$ with $x\gets b$, which is useful because we know $e_b=0$.
$$
0=d_a(b-a)-(b-a)(b-a-1)\implies d_a=b-a-1.\tag5
$$
At last, substituting the formula for $d_a$ in $(5)$ into $(4)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
e_x&=(b-a-1)(x-a)-(x-a)(x-a-1)
\\&=(x-a)(b-x).
\end{align}
$$

I should give credit to John Dawkins, since my answer uses the same method as his answer, just with more details filled in.
